# How to get content from excel textbox using python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, textbox

[image]

I want to use python get content of excel textbox, but i do not have method to solve, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **xlrd package**.

You'll need to install it with **pip** if you haven't already

```
pip install xlrd
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install xlrd
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows machine, try the pypiwin32 package `pip install pypiwin32`

An example where the first worksheet had one textbox with text "hello world":

```
>>> import win32com.client as win32
>>> excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
>>> excel.Visible = False
>>> wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("c:\hello.xlsx")
>>> sheet = wb.Worksheets(1)
>>> canvas = sheet.Shapes
>>> for shp in canvas:
...   print shp.TextFrame2.TextRange
...
hello world
>>>
```