# how to read textbox data in xlsx file using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, textbox, exceldatareader

I have an excel file and I am having data in textbox of the sheet. I want to extract the data from that textbox. I did search all possible modules that I can find in python to parse but nothing is helping here. Is it a bug that needs to be fixed or am I missing something?

Below is the sample of how the data looks like.
[image]

Comment: try [xlwings](https://pypi.org/project/xlwings/) something like this should work `xw.Sheet(1).xl_sheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text` not tested as i don't have any sample to work with.

Comment: how exactly does this work ?
I tried to search for documentation of xlwings. Could you please point out to an example code may be? Above code says sheet don't have an attribute xl_sheet.

Comment: did u read the website linked above  ? https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html

Comment: yes @Datanovice I did go through the documentation and tried out couple of things but no use. When I search for textbox I don't find any results in that documentation. I even tried to get all attributes and dunders using dir to see if that somehow matches our textbox functionality. Sadly nothing is working. May be I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to extract text from textboxes in Excel and found this solution from [yeniv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4045754/yeniv) which worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39915093

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = False
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("c:\hello.xlsx")
sheet = wb.Worksheets(1)
canvas = sheet.Shapes
for shp in canvas:
    print shp.TextFrame2.TextRange
```

...
[output]
hello world
...

And if you want to find out how many textboxes (or shapes with text) there are in the worksheet:

```
len(canvas)
```

And if you want to output the values of each textbox (or shape with text) as a list you can do so by using something like:

```
canvas(1).TextFrame2.TextRange()
```

You can assign a variable to the list.

I found that if you want to replace certain characters within the list you first need to convert to string to run replace() etc.

I also read another thread where it's also possible to first join the list elements as one string, then replace, and then split again.

I'm a newbie Pythoneer and this is my first post so please forgive any oversights. Just wanted to update as I thought I found a workable solution. Cheers!